# Origin of values for "security margin"?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, history

It seems that the acceptable "security margin" for ciphers is set to be between 25% and 30% as a target by designers, where this number represents the number of rounds that remain "unbroken" for a certain worse-case attack.   It is all too eerily empirical from a field that dislikes that sort of thing considering that the security margin tends to decrease over time as attacks improve.

Is there a historical reason for picking this arbitrary number or is there just a consensus that better than 25% is good enough?

Comment: Considering that basically all of modern cryptography rests on a bunch of unproven conjectures that are assumed to be true only because nobody's been able to prove them false, I feel like you may be underrating the "empiricity" of the field. Still, +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen touche.  Usually I can find some mathematical reasoning that makes sense.  This one just seems so arbitrary.

Comment: It won't be arbitrary. Security margin ~ safety factor, and you'll know that safety factors are based on empirical statistics.  Factoid: safety factor for a building = 1.6.

Comment: @PaulUszak You do realize that "factoid" means a false fact blindly repeated by fools, right?

Comment: @forest Like your version of a smaller  $\pi$?

Comment: @PaulUszak A smaller $\pi$? When did I ever say anything like that?

Comment: SImon and Speck have detailed [design specifications](https://nsacyber.github.io/simon-speck/publications/). They include the reasoning behind the safety margins used for the algorithms. See [Notes on the design and analysis of Simon and Speck](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/560.pdf), Section 5, Security Margins. (The authors kind of had to do it because of the politics involved with NSA designs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much reason behind this particular number, but I think that the AES cipher stands as an example. By the time of its selection as AES, Rijndael-128 had 7 out of its 10 rounds broken, though for the 7-round attack it was not clear then if it is better than the exhaustive search. So the security margin was about 30% that time. Now, as the attacks have de-facto advanced by 1 round only (the biclique attacks have only a small constant advantage factor), it is understood that the security margin was well chosen and it made sense to have it 30%.

Answer (score 2):

There is not such a consensus.  For example, Salsa20 has a ‘security margin’ of 60%, with 8 out of 20 rounds broken; for ChaCha, it's 65%, with only 7 out of 20 rounds broken.  But it is all a heuristic pseudo-empirical sociological interpretation of the literature.  A decade and a half ago, EUROCRYPT recommended the reduced-round Salsa20/12 because it was faster, but these days ChaCha with the full 20 rounds is one of the most widely used ciphers on the planet.